# Identification of a apocalyptic zombie movie that I think takes place in Hollywood? Newer, I think?

Tags: story-identification, movie, zombie-apocalypse

In the movie or show I can't remember, there's a bunch of kids that are killing zombies and trying to find a safe place, so I think they go to Hollywood and there's no one there. They're scouting the place, walking through a building when they get startled by something and its this famous guy and he isn't a zombie. But they get scared by him again later while they're scouting and accidentally kill him and they freak out. One of the kids is like "You killed freakin' _________!!!!" or something like that. I would really love to watch this again but I can't remember it. I think it came out recently and I also believe its a comedy.

Comment: When did you see it?  Broadcast TV, cable, theatre or streamed?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*[Zombieland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombieland)* (2009)

> Unaffected college student Columbus (Jesse Eisenberg) is making his way from his college dorm in Austin, Texas, to Columbus, Ohio, to see whether his parents are still alive. He encounters Tallahassee (Woody Harrelson), another survivor, who is particularly violent in killing zombies. Though he does not appear to be sociable, Tallahassee reluctantly allows Columbus to travel with him. Tallahassee mentions he misses his puppy, "Buck" that was killed by zombies, as well as his affinity for Twinkies, which he actively tries to find.
>
> The pair meets Wichita (Emma Stone) and her younger sister Little Rock (Abigail Breslin) in a grocery store. The sisters turn out to be con artists and trick Tallahassee and Columbus into handing over their weapons by pretending that Little Rock is infected by the disease, then stealing their Escalade. The two men find a yellow Hummer H2 loaded with weapons and go after the sisters. However, the girls spring another trap for them and take them hostage. Tallahassee steals his gun back and has a stand-off with Wichita, until Columbus lashes out in anger saying that they have bigger problems to worry about, resulting in an uneasy truce between them.

....

> When the group reaches Hollywood, Tallahassee directs them to the mansion of Bill Murray. Tallahassee and Wichita meet Murray himself, uninfected but disguised as a zombie so he can walk safely around town. Murray is killed when Columbus shoots him, mistaking him for a real zombie during a practical joke while watching Ghostbusters with Little Rock. Columbus realizes during a game of Monopoly that "Buck" was not Tallahassee's puppy, but his young son, who had become infected and died as a result. Wichita and Columbus become increasingly attracted to each other, and Tallahassee bonds with Little Rock, with whom he was previously at odds. Despite Wichita's attraction to Columbus, she fears attachment and leaves with Little Rock for Pacific Playland the next morning. Columbus decides to go after Wichita and convinces Tallahassee to join him.

[From IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1156398/quotes/?tab=qt&ref_=tt_trv_qu)

> **Bill Murray:** [dying] Is that how you say hello where you come from?
> **Columbus:** Oh, my God. Oh, my God, I can't believe I shot Bill Murray.